# How to query jsonb (postgtresql) in feathers/objections ORM?

Tags: postgresql, feathersjs, objection.js

I read the docs from: https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-objection
Still can not query a jsonb column.

My table contains: id, some_other_fields, segmentation: jsonb
Segmentation columns has values like:

`{"type": "WT", "group": "D", "style": 880, "design": 1, "subtype": "ABL"}`

How can I query with, for example, `type = "WT"` ?
Sql code is:

```
select *
from products
where segmentation ->> 'type' = 'WT';
```

but the ORM code:

```
const query = {             
segmentation: {type:"WT"}
};
```

it's not working.

All I manage to get was: `Bad request.... "segmentation" = $1 - invalid input syntax for type json` when playing with syntax or no result at all.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anybody else stumble upon this, the answer is:
in `your_service_name.model.js` you HAVE TO declare json schema with:

```
properties: {
                your_jsonb_property: {type: 'object'}
            }
```

Json schema is optional but it won't work without it.

Answer (score 0):

With objection you should tell ORM when referring json attribute inside a column:

```
.where({'segmentation:type' : 'WT'})
```

Check

https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/recipes/json-queries.html

and

https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/types/#type-fieldexpression

Comment: got error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: productsAPI.find(...).where is not a function` and, when using `'segmentation:type': 'WT'` I got `column "segmentation:type" does not exist"`. I'm 100% sure it's about syntax and this is something easy, I just can't get it to work. :(

Comment: Sounds like that is something feathersjs specific issue.

Comment: Yeah, for sure. I can't get anybody who knows feathers to help me. :(